# Changing jupyter's matching parenthesis color

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, codemirror

How do I change the color of the matching parentheses in jupyter? Regular, square, and curly brackets all appear in bright green when they are shown as matching pairs and it is pretty difficult to see in light background.

Modifying `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` by adding `.CodeMirror-matchingbracket` doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Comment: I know it's been a little while since you asked this but have you tried the answer below?

Comment: Neither of the suggested solutions seem to work any more

Answer (score 2):

In ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css try adding the following:

`.cm-s-ipython .CodeMirror-matchingbracket { color: black !important;}`

If you don't want the color to be black you can use any [webcolors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp) you like.

Answer (score 1):

In `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` I use the following to change the bracket and its background color (the following changes it to red with yellow background but you can modify it as you see fit)

```
div.CodeMirror span.CodeMirror-matchingbracket {
    color: #FF0000;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```