# Jupyter notebook color different parentheses by different colors

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, codemirror

I can see the matching parenthesis hightlights green when I hover around them, but is it possible to add additional color syntax to them so that the matching parenthesis have different colors.

- Is there any nbextension for that?
- Is there a way to add some code to custom.js that will make it happen.

Example code:

```py
# create new features
df = (df
 .withColumn(("rooms_per_hh", F.round(col('total_rooms') / col('households'), 2)))
 .withColumn(("pop_per_hh", F.round(col('pop') / col('households'), 2)))
 .withColumn(("bedrooms_per_rooms", F.round(col('total_bedrooms') / col('total_rooms'), 2)))
     )
```

I like to see different colors for different parentheses here.

Related links:
- [Changing jupyter's matching parenthesis color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686098/changing-jupyters-matching-parenthesis-color)
- [Replace / remove highlighting in Jupyter Notebook with custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45657956/replace-remove-highlighting-in-jupyter-notebook-with-custom-theme)

Required output:
[image]

Comment: You want every single pair of matching brackets to be styled differently, or just the active matching brackets?

Comment: @Souleste all the matching brackets in the cell like in vim editor plugin rainbow parenthesis https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow

Comment: Do you want a "Bracket Pair Colorizer" for Python??

Comment: @spYder Yes, similar to RAINBOW PARENTHESIS in vim.

Comment: Then isn't an option to run the notebooks in VSCode ( w/ the Rainbow or BPC extensios running ) ??? 
You get the different colours that you want + you run .ipynb

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [jupyter-notebook-themes Google Chrome](https://github.com/dobestan/jupyter-notebook-themes) and add `.cm-s-ipython .CodeMirror-matchingbracket { color: black !important;}` or some thing else to change coloring of inner parenthesis.

Then you can add it to your Chrome as a custom extension.

Comment: I like your idea, but I am not sure where to add the code snippet `.cm-s-ipython .CodeMirror-matchingbracket { color: black !important;}` ? after installing chrome extension.

Comment: I mean to add it to the source code of the extension (inside one of its theme) then use that as an extension something like (this)[https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/how-to-install-a-chrome-extension-from-github/]

Comment: You can either fork the repository and commit new changes and do the link above

Answer (score 1):

You can run the jupyter in VSCode, using the Bracket Pair Colorizer ( or Rainbow Brackets ) And will give you something like this : 
**[image: strong text]**

You import the .ipynb file, have the "Run Cell" command + can import the Color extensions....
It's not perfect ( not really using "Jupyter" ) but it works...